# Display a NetCDF file in 3D

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcscene, netcdf

Does anyone know how to display a netCDF in a 3D Scene Map in ArcGIS 10.2? [something like the pretty 3d graphics at the UC](http://www.veooz.com/photos/8HKUfvt.html) I've got hundreds of thousands of points/cells with values for a stretch of time - and I'd like to display/play with symbolization from one file - though at worst I could display each year as from shapefile (cube symbol) and extrude one year atop another - though that sounds tedious.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, I've edited my question to avoid beta tools.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that netCDF's can be difficult to manipulate in ArcGIS and typically require extracting individual layers into shapefiles for most visualizations. They added some capability to create animations with multidimensional feature files in 10.1, but not anything like what you're hoping to do (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000900000001000000). In 10.3, however, there's an out-of-box way to do it if you have the space-time pattern mining toolbox (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/create-space-time-cube.htm).

To do this in base 10.2 you would probably need to pre-process the netCDF into separate features with the data for the top, sides, and bottom and do some clever arranging and projecting to make it look like a cube in the layout view. An alternative would be to just read the NetCDF into R, matlab, python, etc. as an array and make a 3-D plot of that.